# Document Library item

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want to hide the document library items base on who added them. eg if user1 and user2 both add items to the lirary. user1 should not see the item added by user2 and user2 should not see the item added by user1.

is this possible with document liraries?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any option in *Document Library Settings*, but you could try with PowerShell:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://yourhost
$lib = $web.Lists["Yourlib"]
$lib.ReadSecurity = 2
$lib.Update()
$web.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create a view and filter the list items where CreatedBy is [Me].. As below screenshot:

[image]

And then make this view as default... And you can edit the permissions for All Items view and assign only to Administrators or Owners